# RegEx get value from _GET request

Tags: javascript, regex

I'll read more about RegEx in near future, but for now i can't get RegEx for the following:

```
?filter=aBcD07_1-&developer=true
```

Need to get only **aBcD07_1-**, without other. 
Can you please help and provide me a RegEx for javascript

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one:

```
var rx = /[?&]filter=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).*/g;

var result = rx.exec(yourGetStr);

if (result && result.length == 2) {
    alert (result[1]);
}
```

This regular expression will work even when `filter` is not the first query parameter.

Comment: @Vovan: I've changed regular expression a tiny bit so it will work even when `filter` is not the first query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `substring` and `indexOf` should do the trick.

```
var startIndex = str.indexOf('filter=') + 7;
str.substring(startIndex, str.indexOf('&', startIndex)); // returns "aBcD07_1"
```